# How to represent End Line in a String for TestComplete using Javascript

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I need to verify a warning message in TestComplete that has multiple lines for it's innerText property. The innerText looks like this:

```
First Line


Second Line
```

To do that, I thought using \n would be able to represent the end lines

```
  if(warningMessage.innerText == "First Line\n\n\n\nSecond Line")
    Log.Checkpoint("Pass");
  else
    Log.Error("Fail");
```

But it failed. How can I verify this warning message?

Comment: What kind of HTML element is TestComplete ?

Comment: TestComplete is my automation program that I use to automate. Created by Smartbear. The warning message label in question is a web element with the following attributes <SPAN id=warningMessageLabelID>First Line<BR><BR>
<CENTER>Second Line</CENTER></SPAN>

Comment: Try `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: @Helen Using \r\n works. Thank you. Why is this the case? See my solution below for details of how I used \r\n

Comment: @MikeJohnston: On Windows, new line is two characters - \r (0x0D, carriage return) and \n (0x0A, line feed).

Answer (score 1):

So I found 2 solutions:

1. I used `contentText` property as suggested above. This passes only when I include one "\n". My warning label has 3 line-breaks when visually verifying, so this method does not accurately verify the message. See below:

   ```
   if (warningMessage.contentText == "First Line\nSecond Line")
     Log.Checkpoint("Pass");
   else
     Log.Error("Fail");
   ```
2. The next solution is using the `innerText` property, but instead of "\n", I have to use "\r\n", which in Windows character sequence for a new line.

   ```
   if (warningMessage.innerText == "First Line\r\n\r\n\r\nSecond Line")
     Log.Checkpoint("Pass");
   else
     Log.Error("Fail");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could test for the existence of both of those lines with something like:

```
if (warningMessage.innerText.toLowerCase()indexOf('first line') > -1 &&      warningMessage.innerText.toLowerCase()indexOf('second line') > -1 )
{
    Log.Checkpoint("Pass");
}
else
{
    Log.Error("Fail"); 
}
```

Comment: If I cant come up with a way to verify the End Lines with the message, then I could use this workaround. Thanks